# Why doesn't setting 'set_allow_free_revokation' work?

Tags: mods, crusader-kings-2

Just known about the command "set_allow_free_revokation" in decisions\crown_laws.txt

I want to make absolute Crown Authorities can freely revoke titles without tyranny.

I delete the "#" mark, load the game, set crown authorities to absolute, and then I can revoke de jure titles below my empire without tyranny.

But after I saved the game and reload it, I can't revoke it again without tyranny. Took a peek at my save game file, the command "set_allow_free_revokation" is still "yes".

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

allow free revokation only apply's to members of another faith, it's not free if they have the same faith as you.
and unless you change it in your saved game file you will not get the option unless you change your crown laws.